# Error: xindy ask for libncurses.so.5

Tags: errors, xindy, texlive-2020

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 (fresh install) and installed texlive 2020. I got this error in `xindy`

> Process started: texindy "XxxxXxxx".idx
>
> /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy.run: error while loading shared libraries:
>
> libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
>
> Process exited with error(s)

I ran

> xindy --version
>
> xindy release: 2.5.1 xindy script version: 1.18
>
> /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy.run: error while
>
> loading shared libraries: libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object
>
> file: No such file or directory

This is the first time I get this error.

Comment: Do you have the `libncurses5` ubuntu package installed? (The current ncurses version is 6, so probably it isn't installed by default.)

Comment: I already ran `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev` but didn't help.

Comment: That was not enough, then i ran `sudo apt install libncurses5` and things seems to work.

Comment: @TeXnician, could you please turn your comment in to an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the library for ncurses version 5. In Ubuntu that is the package `libncurses5`.

Answer (score 1):

[Related] It is similar on fresh installation of Fedora 32, with installing `dnf install ncurses-compat-libs` (version 6 provides also `libncurses.so.5`).

Answer (score 0):

Fresh install of Manjaro linux required installation or AUR package [ncurses5-compat-libs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ncurses5-compat-libs/)